# Angular2(RxJS) Subscription don't fire at first click

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observer-pattern

I would like to observe the event inside of one componenet and then fire diffrent event i another one. I have declare service and such code inside

```
    private updateIncomingMaterial = new Subject<IncomingMaterial>();

    incomingMaterialUpdate$ = this.updateIncomingMaterial.asObservable();

   updateIncMaterial(incomingMaterialToUpdate: IncomingMaterial) {
       this.updateIncomingMaterial.next(incomingMaterialToUpdate);
   }
```

There is how i fire event in one component

```
    update(model: IncomingMaterial) {
    this.incMatService.updateIncMaterial(model);
    this.isEditorVisible = true;
    this.isUpdateMode = true;
}
```

and here how i want to subscribe it in another one

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subscription = this.incMatService.incomingMaterialUpdate$.subscribe((model: IncomingMaterial) => {
        this.isUpdateMode = true;
        this.imForm.setValue(model);
    });
}
```

I dont know why it never go inside of subscription in the fist time when i click update button(inside i mean this.UpdateMode = true and this.imForm.setValue(model)).

Comment: why are you going down on rxjs and not using Angular Output properties? (see: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs )

Comment: Are both components existing and have the view initialized when you click?

Comment: Because one of them is parent component and i dont know if Output properties is working in such case?

Comment: The view is propably initialized couse is subscripe inside of ngAfterViewInit it goes inside but in first not inside of subscription if I click second time it works

Comment: Ok i had to use ReplaySubject instead of Subject, now it works fine :)